# Wurde der Ausdruck "Schlange stehen" vom Türkischen beeinflusst?

Tags: preposition

Soweit ich weiß, tendiert man im Neudeutschen dazu, manche Präpositionen wegzulassen, z.B

> Bahn fahren, Aldi gehen usw.

Dies liegt meines Wissens daran, dass es im Türkischen keine Präpositionen gibt.
Handelt sich beim Ausdruck "Schlange stehen" um das gleiche Phänomen oder nicht?

Comment: Es ist ein Phänomen in vielen Sprachen, nicht nur in der türkischen, dass Satzbestandteile, die für das Verständnis nicht unbedingt notwendig sind, weggelassen werden.

Comment: Bahn fahren Neudeutsch? https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Bahn+fahren&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=8&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CBahn%20fahren%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @user unknown Klar, wurde vor 1835 nicht verwendet!

Comment: Wenn man "Neudeutsch" durch "Türkendeutsch" ersetzt, passt es vielleicht.

Comment: @userunknown War kurz ob meiner selbst irritiert, aber du hast mich wieder bestätigt.

Comment: Es ist eine irreführende These, dass das Türkische keine Präpositionen kenne. Es gibt durchaus Wörtchen, die räumliche etc. Bezüge bezeichnen. Oft werden sie zwar dem Bezugswort nach- (statt vor-) gestellt, und häufig sind sie grammatikalisiert und werden auch als Kasusendungen beschrieben (*Aldi'**ye*** - zu Aldi, *Aldi'**de*** - bei Aldi, *Istanbul'**dan*** - aus Istanbul; *bisiklet**le*** - mit dem Fahrrad). Diese können auch nicht einfach weggelassen werden, jedenfalls nicht in der Standardsprache. Wenn jemand in wurschtiger Alltagssprache anders spricht, na gut... das ist was anderes.

Comment: PS: Übrigens: schlangestehen = *kuyruk**ta** beklemek* - '**im** Schwanz warten'; ob jetzt natürlich sprachschlampige Türken im Alltag auch postpositions- bzw. kasuslos *kuyruk beklemek* ('Schwanz warten') sagen, weiß ich leider nicht.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Wie erklären Sie dann die Weglassung von Präpositionen, bes. in der Jugendsprache?

Comment: @Dreikäsehoch Faulheit. Simple as that.

Comment: Ich hätte eine These, aber ich weiß nicht, ob sie gut ist. Sie geht von einem bestimmten Grammatik-Erleben des unreflektierten Sprechers im Türkischen aus. Nehmen wir an, ein typischer Sprecher sagte ganz ordentlich *Istanbul'**a** gidiyorum* - Ich gehe **nach** Istanbul. Er 'erlebt' das **-a** als Kasus (Direktiv - wohin?). Im Deutschen findet er nun keinen Kasus "Direktiv", und auch nach Präpositionen keine ersichtliche Kasusflektion am Substantiv: *Ich gehe nach Istanbul-ø.* Er überträgt seine türkische Satzstruktur aufs Deutsche und sagt *Ich gehe Istanbul-ø* (ø = stumme Kasusendung)

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Durch meine Erfahrungen mit Finnen (ebenfalls eine Sprache mit fast keinen Präpositionen, dafür vielen Postpositionen und Fällen, die räumliche Bezüge herstellen) klingt die These für mich plausibel.

Comment: I think many foreigners do that. But I thought that because they are not sure which preposition they should use.. Anyway, der Dialekt heisst Kiezdeutsch.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Bahn fahren** benötigt keine Präposition, weil das Verb *fahren* das Transportmittel bereits als Akkusativobjekt zulässt. *Kuchen essen*, *Zigarre rauchen*, *Mist bauen*, *Schlange stehen*, *Marathon laufen* und die meisten weiteren Verben funktionieren ganz genauso.

Und auch *gehen* ist da keine Ausnahme. Das Akkusativobjekt des Verbs *gehen* beschreibt jedoch den Weg, nicht das Ziel.

> Den Jakobsweg gehen.

*Aldi gehen* oder *Laden gehen* ist daher einfach falsches Deutsch.

Comment: Das ist eine sehr befriedigende Antwort (auch in ihrer Kürze). Der Fall "Aldi gehen" ist damit erledigt. Jedoch das "Schlange stehen" aus der Überschrift vielleicht noch nicht. "Stehen" hat ja (im Normalfall?) kein Akkusativobjekt. Wie erklären wir uns also das? - PS: Hm... oder kann es hin und wieder doch ein Akkusativobjekt haben: "seinen Mann stehen"... ?

Comment: *Die Beine in den Bauch stehen.* Es ist also offensichtlich das Ding, was aus der Ebene ragt.

Comment: ... bzw. das dabei  _entstehende_ Gebilde, wie in  "Spalier stehen" oder "Wache stehen"